# Problems reading a matrix file

Tags: matlab

I have problems correctly reading a matrix.
The source matrix is :

```
  # Source : sampledSurface sampledSurface
  # Faces  : 308
  # Time    sum(magSf)  areaAverage(k)  areaAverage(U)
    1.831000e+04    6.665915e-02    2.019808e-03    (4.761775e-01 -1.966368e-23 -9.890843e-10)
```

My problem is in importing the data inside the brackets. The vector should have 6 columns:

```
A =  
1.831000e+04 6.665915e-02 2.019808e-03 4.761775e-01 -1.966368e-23 -9.890843e-10
```

I have made several attempts to get this working, and I tried to write the code after some research on the internet, but I still have poor results.
I know that my code isn't right.  Here is the code I am attempting to use:

```
filename = 'directory\filename.dat '
delimiter = '\t';

formatSpec = '%s%s%s%s%[^\n\r]'; 

fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter);

fclose(fileID);

raw = repmat({''},length(dataArray{1}),length(dataArray)-1);
for col=1:length(dataArray)-1
    raw(1:length(dataArray{col}),col) = dataArray{col};
end
```

Comment: So what are the problems you found? Edit your question to show us the code you're using.

Comment: Huh? Please add the actual code you use to "read" that matrix. Also it seems to me that `A` does have 6 columns...its a 1x6 vector isn't that what you want? Please give us more details

Comment: @Benoit_11   If I'm asking a question because I have a necessity to help in the solution and not for depriving me points.
Before posting the question I did some research. It is two days I try with incorrect results.
requests come on StackOverflow made after testing various solutions

The problems are two
read scientific notation and read the values in brackets,.

Comment: I did not mean to be offensive sorry if it seems like it; please note that the best way for people here to help you is when you provide as much details as possible about the issue you're having so that we don't spend time guessing what the problem is. And I did not downvote your question; I like to give people a chance to explain themselves and show the effort they made before downvoting.

Comment: @Benoit_11the problem is that StackOverflow is beginning to be for professionals. not everyone uses or know how to use matlab in the right way and often make silly mistakes. I try to put the question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is removing brackets from the line after you have read from the file? You can search the string for a particular substring or pattern and remove it.

We can do it from your `dataArray` variable, so after `fclose(fileID);` put these lines of code:

```
theArrayString = dataArray{4,1}; % this will get the array string from dataArray
theArrayString(regexp(theArrayString,'[(,)]'))=[]; % this uses a regular expression to search for brackets in the string, and where ever it finds a bracket it deletes it (= [])
results = str2num(theArrayString); % this will convert the string into an array of numbers
```

regular expressions are a quick way to do this, but hard to play around with at first. So if you need something similar in future you could also use `strfind('(')` and `strfind(')')` to give you the indexes of where the brackets are, and then delete them from the string, e.g.

```
theArrayString([strfind(theArrayString,'(') strfind(theArrayString,')')]) = []
```

or even using `strrep` to replace a given substring with another (to delete it would be empty), e.g.

`theArrayString = strrep(theArrayString,'(','');`

`theArrayString = strrep(theArrayString,')','');`

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  expression theArrayString = strrep (theArrayString, '(', '') has been very effective, I would like to optimize the code.
I have noticed that in the import automatic Matlab code contains the expression 'regexp ()' within a For loop.  I found a mistake in the expression index: theArrayString ([strfind (theArrayString, '(') strfind (theArrayString, ')')]) = []